# Tsunami : power of destruction

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, everyday-life, tsunami

I'm not sure this is the good place to ask those questions. Sorry if it isn't.

Are there studies that evaluated the resistance of buildings against tsunami ? What kind of buildings could manage a tsunami with waves of 30 meters ? or a mega tsunami with waves of 100 meters ?

Are underground buildings safe in those cases ?

Is the potential of destruction directly linked to the height of waves on the shore ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a [PDF](http://www.fzk.uni-hannover.de/fileadmin/institut/Veranstaltungen/DFG-RT/DFG-pdf/1.2.1_-_Yeh__Harry_-_DFGTsunamiForce.pdf) that addresses tsunami structural forces in quantitative detail. Covered are hydrostatic, buoyant, hydrodynamic, surge, impact and breaking wave forces.

Comment: Reading this document, I realized that nothing can stand such a thing like a megatsunami. Thanks for the link, that's what I needed !